# SSL certificate signature verification

Tags: ssl, certificate, signature, verification

I'm trying to verify certificate on an embedded board manually because it doesn't support Openssl or other libraries.  However it does have libraries for MD5 and SHA1 hashes and RSA encryption.

From what I understand to verify the certificate, first compute the SHA1 hash (or MD5) of the certificate; then decode the signature using CA's public key to obtain a hashed value.  These two hash values should be the same.

SHA1 hash produces a 20 byte value and MD5 produces 16 byte value.  However, RSA decoding of the signature does not.  If the CA's key is 1024 bits, the decode signature will be 80bytes; if the CA's key is 512 bits, the decoded signature will be 40 bytes.  So I can't really compare the 20 bytes SHA1 value against the 40 or 80 bytes Decoded Signature.

Am I doing something wrong?  Or am I missing a step?

Comment: FYI: I'm trying to use a embedded board to verify incoming certificates.  These certificates will be generated and signed by a private CA generated using Openssl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing bit is the padding algorithm.

You use RSA with a specific padding algorithm, and the same algorithm also tells you how to take the result (when you decrypt the signature) and extract from it the actual data (the hash).

Comment: Thanks for the info,
I have a follow up question.  When I use openssl to sign certificates "openssl ca -config ca.cnf -policy policy_anything -out certs/certificate.crt -infiles request.csr"  The default padding method used by Openssl is PKCS#5?  Please correct me if I'm wrong that there is no way to change it?  I believe there are no options for CA command or anything in the ca.cnf file that allows us to pick the Padding method?

Comment: I think i made a mistake in the comment above. Openssl uses PKCS#1 for padding, private/public key, and everything to do with certificates?  And I guess there is no way to tell Openssl to us 0 Padding since I can't find options in CA command no ca.cnf file.

Comment: I don't think the padding can be changed using the command line tool. If you're up for writing some code, it's possible. But you need a very good reason not to pad your input (for example if you do your own padding), otherwise you could introduce weaknesses into the scheme.