# Issues while manually verifying SSL digital signatures

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, wireshark, signature

I'm currently trying to verify digital signatures of ssl certificates using just wireshark and my Java IDE (eclipse). In order to do that, from what I have read [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.1.3), I need to:

1. Compute the hash of the ASN.1 DER encoded **tbsCertificate** using the proper algorithm, which is  specified in the certificate itself. (usually SHA-256)
2. Use the certificate issuer's public key to decode the signature, again using the specified algorithm (usually RSA)
3. Compare the two results, which should be identical.

Now, I have been able both to compute the hash and to decrypt the signature, however I have encountered a problem: the RSA decoding of the signature deosn't exactly result in an hash, but in a longer string which looks like this:

`3031300d0609608648016503040201050004206b6cba600a70b90a806e9bf42d71d2253f762b8090fb021a6863e60feb3dd421`  (hex)

While googling, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694210/ssl-certificate-signature-verification) which explains why the RSA decoding of the signature doesn't match the hash. Apparently, the string contains the hash *and* some padding because of security issues.
After a further small research, in a sample of 3 decoded signatures , it appears that the string

`3031300d060960864801650304020105000420`

(which I think to be the padding) is constant in all of the decoded signatures , while the remaining (which I think to be the hash) is always a different string of the same length of an SHA-256 hash.

Needless to say, the computed hash and the one extracted from the decoded signature don't match.  What am I getting wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Notes:

1. I use the Wireshark protocol dissector to extract the data needed (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPCH9.png)) . I copy the part of the packet as an hexadecimal flux and then I use the following  function to convert it into a byte array.

   ```
    public static byte[] hexToBytes(String hexString)
    {
        int len = hexString.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) 
        {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(hexString.charAt(i), 16) 
            << 4) + Character.digit(hexString.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }
   ```
2. I assume that the data of the packet is already in the ASN.1 DER format. (Am I wrong?)

Comment: First observation: "padding" almost always (I would say always but I am sure someone will find a cryptic counter example) is done at the end of some content, so should not be the prefix. So I would think you are on a wrong path there...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll try to figure out what's wrong. If someone has any idea, feel free to suggest. Thanks in advance